# ng-if doesn't works as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a buttons array in my model, and an 'ng-if' in the template for each button:

```
self.aButtons.push({
                label: __('Siguiente'),
                class: 'btn-moduloAvance',
                show: (self.oContrato.definirPago || self.oContrato.horario_definido)
                }
            });
```

That's the Html:

```
  <button ng-if="boton.show"
          ng-repeat="boton in personaAndContrato.aButtons"
          type="button"
          ng-class="boton.class"
  />
```

I know that i'm assigning a boolean to the 'show' property, so it's impossible it changes because it's a simple type.

By the way I'm trying to assign a function to the 'show' property but i'm getting the following error:

```
    self.aButtons.push({
                label: __('Siguiente'),
                class: 'btn-moduloAvance',
                show: function () {
                    return (self.oContrato.definirPago || self.oContrato.horario_definido);
                }
            });
```

Html (edited):

```
<button ng-if="boton.show()"
      ng-repeat="boton in personaAndContrato.aButtons"
      type="button"
      ng-class="boton.class"
/>
```

> TypeError: v2.show is not a function
>       at fn (eval at compile (angular.js?version=alpha.1:14539), :4:240)

Some ideas? Does i'm missing or missunderstanding something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ng-show is less obtrusive than ng-if, and the final result is similar, but accepted to be used with ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` in the same tag if `ng-if` refer to the inner variable of `ng-repeat`.

Just split it :

```
<div ng-repeat="boton in personaAndContrato.aButtons">
    <button ng-if="boton.show()"
      type="button"
      ng-class="boton.class"
   />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing to `ng-if="boton.show()"` will do.